Personalizar PaletteOptions de Mui con Typescript en React
Tengo este archivo colors.ts:
const colors = {
  background: {
    default: '#f8f9fa',
  },

  text: {
    main: '#67748e',
    focus: '#67748e',
  },

  transparent: {
    main: 'transparent',
  },

  white: {
    main: '#ffffff',
    focus: '#ffffff',
  },
  .
  .
  .
}

export default colors



Y tengo este archivo donde llamo al createTheme:

import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'
import colors from 'plantilla/assets/theme/base/colors'
createTheme({
  breakpoints: { ...breakpoints },
  palette: { ...colors },
  typography: { ...typography },
  boxShadows: { ...boxShadows },
  borders: { ...borders },
  .
  .
  .
})


Y obtengo este error en el palette: { ...colors },:

El tipo '{ background: { default: string; }; text: { main: string; focus: string; }; transparent: { main: string; }; white: { main: string; focus: string; }; black: { light: string; main: string; focus: string; }; primary: { ...; }; ... 15 more ...; tabs: { ...; }; }' no se puede asignar al tipo 'PaletteOptions'.
  Los tipos de propiedad 'text' no son compatibles.
    El tipo "{ main: string; focus: string; }" no tiene propiedades en común con el tipo "Partial<TypeText>".


Cómo puedo personalizar el PaletteOptions para que pueda admitir todo lo que tengo en colors?
Estoy usando "@mui/material": "^5.16.4",
Intenté el module augmentation que dice en la documentación de Mui pero no logro solucionarlo.
